# Is one dimesional cubic NLS is globally wellposed in $H^{s}(\mathbb R), (0<s<1)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

We consider the one dimensional cubic nonlinear Shr\"odinger equation (NLS):
$$i\partial_{t}\phi (x,t) +\Delta \phi (x,t)= \pm |\phi (x,t)|^{2} \phi(x,t),  \ (x, t\in \mathbb R),$$
$$\phi (x,0) = \phi_{0}(x)\in H^{s}(\mathbb R);$$
where $H^{s}(\mathbb R)$ is usual Sobolev space.

In 1978  [Ginibre-Velo](https://eudml.org/doc/75982) have shown that the above NLS is globally wellposed: that is, for the initial data in $\phi_{0}\in H^{1}(\mathbb R)$, the NLS has  a unique solution in $C(\mathbb R, H^{1}(\mathbb R)).$ In 1987 [Yoshio   Tsutsumi](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp%2FFE%2FFE_pdf_with_bookmark%2FFE21-30-en_KML%2Ffe30-115-125%2Ffe30-115-125.pdf&ei=wcEPVZWWGpeIuATt24CwCA&usg=AFQjCNGKhLzeaJ20OTB2tApHREXUJJiZJQ&sig2=H1Cerdlal1rw9UAgAihqCA&bvm=bv.88528373,d.c2E)   have shown that: for the initial data in $\phi_{0}\in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$,  the NLS has  a unique global solution in $C(\mathbb R, L^{2}(\mathbb R)).$

We note that, $H^{1}(\mathbb R)\subset H^{s}(\mathbb R) \subset H^{0}(\mathbb R)=L^{2}(\mathbb R), (0<s<1).$

> **My Question**: Let  $\phi_{0}\in H^{s}(\mathbb R), (0<s<1).$
>   Is it true that for the given initial data $\phi_{0}\in H^{s}(\mathbb R),$ the cubic NLS has a unique global  solution in $C(\mathbb R, H^{s}(\mathbb R))$ ? If yes, how to prove it ?  (or proper reference ?)

[See also this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200331/global-well-posedness-of-cubic-nls-in-for-initial-data-in-hs-mathbb-r-0s) on MO]

Thanks,

Edit:
**Vague Ideas**:

Fact: Suppose we have a local existence for cubic NLS in $H^{s}(0<s<1):$ that is, for the given initial time $u(t_{0}, x)=u_{0}(x)\in H^{s}(0<s<1), $ the cubic NLS has a unique local solution in $C(\mathbb [t_{0}, t_{0}+T_{1}^{*}]: H^{s}(\mathbb R)).$ (I guess this true)

Now one may apply the above result for the initial time  $t_{0}+T_{1}^{\ast}$: more specifically,  for the given initial data, $u(t_{0}+T^{\ast})=u_{0}(x)\in H^{s}(\mathbb R) \ (0<s<1);$  the NLS has unique local solution in $C([t_{0}+T^{\ast},t_{0}+T^{\ast}+T^{\ast}_{1}], H^{s}(\mathbb R)).$

If we start with $I_{1}= [t_{0}, t_{0}+T_{1}^{*}]$, $I_{2}=[t_{0}+T_{1}^{\ast}, t_{0}+T_{1}^{\ast}+T_{2}^{\ast}]$, and so on... .; and it will cover $[t_{0}, \infty)$). And on each individual intervals (as explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200331/global-well-posedness-of-cubic-nls-in-for-initial-data-in-hs-mathbb-r-0s) ) $I_{j}$ we have a solution of cubic NLS in $C(I_{j}: H^{s}(\mathbb R)).$

> **My difficulties**: But does it mean that the cubic NLS has a global solution in $C([t_{0}, \infty): H^{s}(\mathbb R))$ ? (Or I have to do bit more work to conclude this fact ?)